# Not modify derived variables

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to modify a json file with several functions.

I load my initial json as :

```
entry_file = json.loads("insert formatted str")
```

I'm adding different fields to the new dict created with functions like:

```
def add_specificfield(object_to_modify, field_name, field_value):
        object_to_modify["field_name"] = field_value
        return(object_to_modify)
```

Other functions involve loops etc etc.. each time I want to test an output I pass my entry file through the function but I create a "copy" variable to avoid reloading "entry_file" just before,
so I do `entry_file_copy = entry_file`

When I call the function and pass the entry_file, it modifies both entry_file and entry_file_copy.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are mutable (like dicts or lists), a = b means that a and b now references the same underlying memory (think C pointers, if you're familiar with it).

If you want an actual copy (different memory) you have to use entry_file.copy().

If entry_file itself contains mutable objects, you may need entry_file.deepcopy() or face the same problem recursively.
See the doc for more details https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html